# How to validate a field as soon as it loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, backbone.js

I am learning web development. And I have a login form where I have two text field one for email and one for password. I want to have validation for email field. Currently, I am able to validate but it occurs when I click on submit button. Is there an way I can do the validation as soon as the email field loses focus. I want to call `validateEmail` method as soon as focus loses.

This is what I have till now:

**HTML File**

```
<div id="ErrMsg" style="color:red">
    <form id="myForm" action = "" method="post">
        <input id="email" name="Email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <input id="pass" name="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
        <button id="signIn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
    </form>
```

**JS File**

```
window.loginView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click #signIn': 'doSignIn',
        },
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('Initializing Login View');
        },
        validateEmail: function(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        },
        doSignIn: function(event) {
            $("#ErrMsg").text("");
            var email = $("#email").val();
            // checking if email is valid
            if (!this.validateEmail(email)) {
                $("#ErrMsg").text(email + " is not valid :(");
            }
            else
            {
            // some logic to fetch data from REST
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can bind an `focusout` event.

**EDIT:**
add another event (after `'click #signIn': 'doSignIn'`):

```
'focusout #signIn': 'doSignIn'
```

Comment: Can you kindly provide any snippet.

Comment: It should be `#email` . As I want it to be applied it for email field. Kindly guide

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just change `doSignIn` function to `validateEmail`

Comment: I doubt that, Actually I want the email field to be verified. So for that I need `'focusout #email': 'validateEmailFunction'`

Comment: I do not want the event to be triggered for signIn button. Am I making sense?

Comment: So when the focus is out of email field I want the `focusout` to be triggered.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with backbone, but imho you have to call anonymous `function() { if ( !this.validateEmail( $("#email").val() ) ) { $("#ErrMsg").text(email + " is not valid :("); }`

This should trigger validation and show `#ErrMsg`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jquery see this https://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
$("#email").blur(validateEmail)
```

(obviously this requires a function named validateEmail)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you kindly tell me where shall I place this method as per my code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with backbone.js. I guess it makes coding easier, but in doing so reduces the opportunities for customization. You need to take the  email validation function an put it in a global context, but I have no idea what implications this would have on the rest of the code in this framework, so I can't advise.